# how to wrap forms with an already written outer form in paredit

Tags: emacs, lisp, paredit

Suppose I have this code

```
(hello world)
(hi world)
```

Then it comes to my mind that I should wrap that with the following form:

```
(let (acc)
  <>
  (nreverse acc))
```

resulting in this code:

```
(let (acc)
  (hello world)
  (hi world)
  (nreverse acc))
```

Here is how I usually do the wrapping. First I write an incomplete outer form before the to-be-wrapped forms like this:

```
(let (acc))
(hello world)
(hi world)
```

Then I press `C-)` (`paredit-forward-slurp-sexp`) twice to slurp things:

```
(let (acc)
  (hello world)
  (hi world))
```

Then I finish up by adding `(nreverse acc)` at the end.

Now what I wonder is what if I started by first writing the complete outer form template like this?

```
(let (acc)
  (nreverse acc))
(hello world)
(hi world)
```

or like this

```
(hello world)
(hi world)
(let (acc)
  (nreverse acc))
```

Is there a short sequence of paredit or non-paredit commands that I can press to finish the job from that start?

I could move point, cut the two to-be-wrapped forms, move point, paste the forms. But I am wondering if there is a more convenient way.

I am satisfied with how I do the wrapping, but it feels like I might be missing some other neat editing tricks which are to be found from a different start.

Comment: If all fails, use a keyboard macro. You could also extend paredit to do whatever you want. GNU Emacs is extensible.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of repeatedly using `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp` or kill-yank'ing the region, you can mark the region of sexps to enclose and use `paredit-wrap-round` <kbd>M-(</kbd>

If I were typing your example I would start with the last expression:

```
(hello world)
(hi world)
(nreverse acc)_
```

<kbd>C-SPC</kbd> <kbd>C-M-a</kbd> <kbd>C-M-a</kbd> <kbd>C-M-a</kbd> <kbd>M-(</kbd> yields:

```
(_(hello world)
  (hi world)
  (nreverse acc))
```

Insert `let (acc)` and finish with <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-M-h</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> to reindentify.

There's probably a better way =), but even if you don't use `transient-mark-mode` you can supply other options to wrapping:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd> wraps to the end of buffer or the enclosing list
- <kbd>C-u #</kbd> wraps the following `#` expressions

See the docstring for `paredit-wrap-sexp`

Comment: This. Note that simply using `(` when the region is active and when `transient-mark-mode` is enabled will achieve the same thing as using `paredit-wrap-sexp`. I use it, and it makes wrapping regions with parenthesis feel natural.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at redshank, a emacs package that does a bunch of useful things like this. Works with paredit very nicely.